# How to find the rank of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

Find the rank of

$$\begin{pmatrix}
4y+2z & 4x+4  & 2x-1 \\ 
y+2 & x & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $(x,y,z)$ satisfy $4xy + 2xz + 4y - z = xy + 2x - z = 0$.

Comment: Please provide some context. For example, where did you encounter the problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: We can solve this to get
$$
y = -(2 (2 x^2 - x))/(2 x^2 + 3 x + 4)
$$

Comment: I think I was able to solve it , I supposed that the rank is less than 2 , that is 1,  then the two row vectors are collinear , so there exists a constant such that they're linearly dependent , then I reached a contradiction after some calculations , so there is no such constant, and hence the rank is 2

Comment: Better way than mine to solve it! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you solve the system $4xy+2xz+4y-z=xy+2x-z=0$ for $x$ you obtain :

$$y=\frac{2x(1-2x)}{2x^2+3x+4},z=\frac{8x(x+1)}{2x^2+3x+4}$$

So we can rewrite the matrix $M$ as :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{24x}{2x^2+3x+4} & 4x+4  & 2x-1 \\ 
\frac{8(x+1)}{2x^2+3x+4}& x & -1
\end{pmatrix}  $$

Via gaussian elimination (and a good amount of algebra) we get the reduced matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0  & \frac{-4x^4-12x^3-25x^2-24x-16}{8(x^2+8x+4)} \\ 
0& 1 & \frac{2x^2+4x-1}{x^2+8x+4}
\end{pmatrix}  $$

So $Rank(M)=2$.